# Strange result with SED Pattern and Hold space

Tags: sed

I have the following SED Code, that extracts a username along with their date of birth and displays it on one line. User name and date of birth are are two separate lines.

The issues is that hold buffer is not being over written each time a name is encountered and stored.  sometimes it can show about 10 users properly, but sometimes it displays the same name (2 or 3 times). see current results.

```
sed -rn \  
    -e '/^Name:/{  
       s/Local:.*//
       s/Name: //
       s//\1/  
       h  
       }'\   

    -e '/DOB:/{
        s/(.*DOB:\s([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}).*)/\2/
        #s/(.*DOB:\s(.*)\sMem.*)/\2/
        G
        s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\t\1/
        p
       }' $f
```

I thought code above  would give me an output similar to:

**Current Results**

```
Tito Puente     8/21/1999  
Tito Puente     23/13/1967  
ARON BYRDMAN    6/24/1320  
JOE P. EARTHE   9/7/1961  
WISTON P. GREY  HEAVEN, NY 10121 DOB: Mem Status: Journeyman  
WISTON P. GREY  42/12/1949
```

[Sample Data](https://textuploader.com/1d7d0)

I have tried various options to no avail. does any have a clue?

Comment: It looks like you're depending on `Local` being on the same line as `Name`, and that's clearly not the case for all names.

Comment: true,  when i run that command separately the proper output is  given.

Comment: muru, you were on the Money!  i added s/Local:.*// and  s/Name: // to standardize the line!

Comment: Could you possibly post the expected results vs. the results you are currently getting.  When I try your code, it delivers results on the same format that you show, but it's unclear whether this is what you expect or not.